# Vincular link de endereço com aplicativos de GPS

Tags: javascript, api, gps

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida, eu estou desenvolvendo uma plataforma de anúncios e me deparei com uma questão aqui.

O meu anunciante se cadastra na plataforma preenche as informações coloca seu endereço e um mapa do google a minha dúvida e a seguinte: Através do endereço desse anunciante eu consigo colocar algum link que quando algum usuário clicar abra diretamente no Waze por exemplo? ou em qualquer outro aplicativo de GPS?

Não sei se isso é algum código pronto ou API será que é possível?

Comment: Seria algo assim que você busca fazer ou associar - [Google Latitude](http://www.techtudo.com.br/tudo-sobre/google-latitude.html)

Comment: Google Latitude não está mais disponível. Se você deseja experimente com [Glympse](https://www.glympse.com/) ou [Foursquare](https://foursquare.com/)

Comment: @DiegoHenrique tem algum link de estudo sobre ?

Comment: Veja no rodapé Glympse e no topo Foursquare, ambos tem API

Comment: Acesse - API [Glympse](https://developer.glympse.com/) e no [Foursquare](https://developer.foursquare.com/)

Comment: Dê uma olha nisso - [Google Maps - Fórum de Suporte](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps-pt/uiLo1V1ArIY)

Comment: Bom, acho que estes links serão úteis a você, e não precisará doar mais seus meros 50 pontos a alguém. A não ser que, esse alguém apareça por aqui com todo [algoritmo](https://m.tecmundo.com.br/programacao/2082-o-que-e-algoritmo-.htm) elaborado pra você usar. rsrs

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi rs se eu não marcar uma resposta esses 50 pontos retornam para mim? rs obrigado acho que vai ajudar mesmo decidi por em destaque pois precisava muito de um norte sabe para poder implementar esse tipo de tecnologia muito obrigado amigo salvou

Comment: ok entendi obrigado mesmo <3

Comment: Os pontos não retornam. ( só pra avisar )

Comment: Na [ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty): **Todas as gratificações são pagas de antemão e não são reembolsáveis em caso algum.**

Comment: dica: https://www.habaneroconsulting.com/stories/insights/2011/opening-native-map-apps-from-the-mobile-browser

Comment: minha resposta não atende o que você precisa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim você consegue. Se você tem o endereço, pode obter as coordenadas de latitude e longitude. Com isso, você pode usar um recurso do *Waze* chamado *Deep Links*.

É uma *API* baseada em url que você pode utilizar para abrir diretamente o App do *Waze* caso esteja instalado, ou então abrir diretamente o site.

A url tem que ter esse formato:

```
https://www.waze.com/location?ll=latitude,logitude
```

Exemplo:

https://www.waze.com/location?ll=-23.5498601,-46.6362092

É possível fazer pesquisas e usar chamadas nativas de *Android* ou *iOS*, veja mais aqui: https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/